# United States Qwerty keyboard buggy

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, qwerty

I'm using Windows 10 build 1903 with the layout set to United States Qwerty English International. However to do such things as type a quote(`""`) with `SHIFT` plus the quote key, I need to use a lot of force which is time consuming and uncomfortable. This doesn't happen for other input types.

I could use an on-screen keyboard to solve the issue but that is my least favourite option. How can I best solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The keyboard cannot know how hard you are pressing - what makes you believe it can?

Comment: It is specifically an issue with this layout, it lags behind. If I use any other layout, everything is fine and I don't need to press so hard. My thinking is that something in the settings causes this "bug", I had to  press twice to get these("").

Comment: Again... The keyboard cannot know how hard you are pressing.

Comment: I understand, my point is that the only reason I have to use force is due to not having anything appear on first try. It's also worth mentioning that CTRL + ALT + I for instance produces this: í which in the IDE I use should have created a new chunk.

Comment: Force is nothing to do with it. Repetition is what does it. You have set a keyboard layout that uses dead-keys. Type `'` then `e`. Nothing happens until you press the `e` & then you get `é`. If you don't want that, don't use International, use British or US.

Comment: The issue is that the use keyboards have \\ and the back ticks switched. I also can't use `|` without first using an on-screen keyboard. As a "programmer", these are fundamental keys that I work with so often hence the need to use English International. It's perhaps not very important to note that the keys work well when I'm on a Unix machine. The only input that works fine is IBM Arabic or something like that.

Comment: Basically you first need to set the correct physical keyboard, then whether you need ISO or ANSI. The rest of the non-ASCII peripheral layout can change massively by language.

Comment: // Thanks everyone, I changed my region to the US & that fixed it. //

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen a keyboard layout that uses dead-keys to provide accent options, such as é ü à ñ etc.

If you don't want those options then select a non-International keyboard layout from Control Panel > Region & Language > Keyboards & Language > Change Keyboards...

[image]

Here I have first set my Language to the correct one for my physical keyboard & Location (English UK), then underneath I have a switch between US International (with the dead-keys) & 'standard' UK Extended (without dead-keys).
The switch between US & UK is because it also moves the locations of `@` and `"` which clash with my usual Mac keyboard layout which I'm most accustomed to.

Comment: Perfect, my regional settings were to blame I guess.